# error during app installation on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When I am installing my app on device this error is coming..
[image]

I am searching on net since yesterday found many tips and also applied but it fruitless.

Please guide me what to do ?

Comment: I think you've forgotten to include the error?

Comment: @Dolbz it is mentioned in screen shot.

Comment: ah my bad. I think I'm behind a proxy that is blocking it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the valid code sign identity of your corresponding device in your xcode project(i.e) valid provisioning profile.

Answer (score 1):

Verify the following things,

1.Login to your developer account, and in the provisioning portal confirm that the corresponding device is added.

2.Have you install the provisional file into your device?

3.Check your build settings that you have choose the correct code sign identity.